# Bootstrap 3 markup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

could you please help me, how I can implement following.
This is my html markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <!--Navigation-->
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
        <img class="img-responsive" id="bg" src="img/about-us.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the image inside of second div to be solid backgound for this div (without scrolling, and image should be allways centered).

Comment: why not just use background-image: url(...) attribute ?
and you can give it background-position: centered ?

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap 3 there is a class for centering columns

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10 centered"> <img class="img-responsive" id="bg" src="img/about-us.jpg"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class or id markup to the second div and link it with the image using css. Something like this:

HTML:

`<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        ...
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10" id="img-box"></div>
</div>`

CSS:

`#img-box {
    background-image: url(../img/about-us.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        ...
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10" id="img-div"></div>
</div>

#img-div{
background-image: url(img/about-us.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}
```